# azure media services v3 - how to change Media Reserved Unit type & count?

Tags: azure-media-services

**How to change Media Reserved Unit type & count in the V3 API?**

Can currently be changed from V2, however I don't see anything about reserved units in the api?

**V2 Version**

```
CloudMediaContext AzureContext;
var reservedUnit = AzureContext.EncodingReservedUnits.FirstOrDefault();
reservedUnit.ReservedUnitType = reservedUnitType;
reservedUnit.CurrentReservedUnits = units;
reservedUnit.Update();
```

**Reference**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-scale-media-processing-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.azuremediaservicesclient?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

> azure media services v3 - how to change Media Reserved Unit type & count?

Unfortunately, it is not supported in the Azure media service v3 currently. Media Reserved Units can only be managed using the Media Services v2 API. It is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-from-v2-to-v3#known-issues).

For more information about changes that were introduced in Azure Media Services (AMS) v3, shows differences between two versions, and provides the migration guidance, please refer to [Migration guidance for moving from Media Services v2 to v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-from-v2-to-v3).

> **Known issues**
>
> - Currently, you cannot use the Azure portal to manage v3 resources. Use the REST API, CLI, or one of the supported SDKs.
> - **Today, Media Reserved Units can only be managed using the Media Services v2 API. For more information, see [Scaling media processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-scale-media-processing-overview).**
> - Media Services entities created with the v3 API cannot be managed by the v2 API.
>   It is not recommended to manage entities that were created with v2 APIs via the v3 APIs. Following are examples of the differences that make the entities in two versions incompatible: